# How can I make labels invisible on load in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access-2007

I've got a logger form which hides the text and combo boxes until you hit the "start activity" but is there anyway I can also make the labels disappear on load also and then also appear once a start button is pressed?

Here is a sample of my code:

Private Sub Form_Load()

strUserID = Environ("USERNAME")

```
AppVersion = "Version - " & DLookup("Version", "Version", "ID = 1") & " - " & DLookup("VersionDate", "Version", "ID = 1")
Me.txtVersion = AppVersion
Me.cmdStartCall.Visible = True
Me.txtPolicyClaimReference.Visible = False
Me.txtJobReference.Visible = False
Me.txtNotes.Visible = False
Me.CboContactMethod.Visible = False
Me.CboTitle.Visible = False
Me.CboDepartment.Visible = False
Me.CboLocation.Visible = False
Me.txtScheme.Visible = False
Me.txtFirstName.Visible = False
Me.txtSurname.Visible = False
```

End Sub

So if we assume that each txt or cbo box has the same name label, how can i get them not to show unless activated?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: If the labels are attached to their textboxes/comboboxes, they should be hidden automatically with them.

Comment: Hi Andre they are separate labels - does that mean I need to reapply the textboxes/comboboxes with attached labels for this to work?

Comment: yeah that solved it - thanks for your help Andre - any chance you can put it as an actual answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels must be attached (associated) to their textboxes/comboboxes, then they are hidden automatically with them.

To attach separated labels:

- Select the label
- Issue the Cut command
- Select the control to which you want to attach the label
- Issue the Paste command.

(from http://www.consultdmw.com/access-control-labels.htm)

Comment: Thanks very much Andre!